# VB.NET - ThreadPool and delegate in c# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, asynchronous

Hey, how this is written in VB.NET? This was an example I found on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SynchronousSilverlight.aspx.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
 var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISimpleService>("*");
 var simpleService = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
 var asyncResult = simpleService.BeginGetGreeting("Daniel", null, null);
 string greeting = null;
 try
 {
  greeting = simpleService.EndGetGreeting(asyncResult);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  DisplayMessage(string.Format(
    "Unable to communicate with server. {0} {1}", 
   ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
 }
 DisplayGreeting(greeting);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be a few syntax errors but I am sure you can resolve them.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf GetGreeting))

Private Sub GetGreeting(o As Object)
    Dim channelFactory = New ChannelFactory(Of ISimpleService)("*")
    Dim simpleService = channelFactory.CreateChannel()
    Dim asyncResult = simpleService.BeginGetGreeting("Daniel", Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim greeting As String = Nothing
    Begin Try
        greeting = simpleService.EndGetGreeting(asyncResult)
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayMessage(String.Format("Unable to communicate with server. {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace))
    End Try
    DisplayGreeting(greeting)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not use this example on the Code Project directly:) It was mainly WaitCallback() I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

In VB10 (VS2010) you can do a rather literal translation:

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
          Sub()
           Console.WriteLine("Hello")
          End Sub)
```

And note that there are not linecontinuations (_) necessary here.

But you probably want this for VS2008 and then you need to break out the delegate as a separate Sub or Function.

```
Sub Main()
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf CallBack, "Hello")
End Sub

Sub CallBack(ByVal state As Object)
   Console.WriteLine(state)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is a real shame that you save almost no typing when using the anonymous delegate in VB10. (I do love that they got rid of those ridiculous line endings though.)

Answer (score 0):

To provide a little explanation of the differences (other's have provided good code samples):

VB.NET doesn't support anonymous methods, which are supported in C# by using the `delegate {}` syntax to define an inline method.  To convert that syntax to VB.NET you have to move the contents of the anonymous inline method out into a normal method, then use a Delegate pointed at the extracted method to initiate the call.

When both are compiled they are essentially the same, since anonymous methods in C# are really only anonymous in their pre-compiled state (the compiler generates names for the methods and then treats them as first-class methods).